# Haskell Image Processing (HIP) operate on Pixel RGB

Tags: image, haskell, rgb, hip

I'm new to this library and I want a way to operate a (for example) Pixel RGB Double like:

```
p <- <RGB:(1.0e-2|9.80392156862745e-4|9.900990099009901e-3)>
```

I know substracts or sums affects the whole RGB

```
pixel p = p + 1
<RGB:(1.01|1.0009803921568627|1.00990099009901)>
```

Is there a way to operate the Red, Blue or Green part alone instead of operate the three colors at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `RGB`, the data declaration looks like this:

```
data instance Pixel RGB a = PixelRGB a a a
```

The three fields are the red, green, and blue fields, respectively. So you can do all the usual Haskell-y things like pattern matching and reconstructing. For example:

```
redder (PixelRGB r g b) = PixelRGB ((r+1)/2) g b
```

The data declarations for other instances of this data family are shown at the top of [the main documentation page](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hip-1.5.6.0/docs/Graphics-Image.html).